# how to clear screen in cmder Im using mysql [mariadb]

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cmder

```
MariaDB \[(none)\]\> ! clear;
ERROR: Unknown command '!'.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '! clear' at line
```

I searched a lot for this problem and did all the solutions but to no avail and the problem still persists

Comment: What is your OS ?  ... the command depends upon the MySQL/MariaDB client version as well. If Linux, maybe try with: `\! clear` or Windows try with: `\! cls`. See the very last comment [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58680).

Comment: I'm used windows 10 and used xampp

Answer (score 0):

Use **system cls**
In fact you call any console commands by using **system** followed with any command, for example **system dir** to show the list of files in a directory.